# "Your OS" when installing Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I would like to install Istio into my Kubernetes cluster.  The [installation page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/) says to:

> download the installation file for your OS

My developer machine is a Windows 10 machine.  The nodes in my Kubernetes cluster run CentOS.

**When it says "Your OS" does it mean my machine that I will download it to and run it from, or does it mean the OS that my cluster runs on?**  (or do I need to run it from a node in the cluster?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download basically has `istioctl` and some samples in it.

So you want to download for the OS that you are running the command from (in my case Windows 10).